# Permutation growing algorithm in Python and print strings

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation

I've done this algorithm before, in school, but I've forgotten how to do it. Basically I want to return a result that are strings like 'a[0]', 'a[0].a[0]' ...

```
length = range(0,2) #length = 2
depth = range(0,3)  #depth = 3

for i in length:
    for k in depth:
        …   print each permutation
```

RESULT

```
a[0]
a[0].a[0]
a[0].a[1]
a[0].a[0].a[0]
a[0].a[0].a[1]
a[0].a[1].a[0]
a[0].a[1].a[1]
a[1]
a[1].a[0]
a[1].a[1]
a[1].a[0].a[0]
a[1].a[0].a[1]
a[1].a[1].a[0]
a[1].a[1].a[1]
```

Comment: If you change length or depth so that they are not equal, then what do the results look like?

Comment: What is the logic in the ordering of the result? Why are `a[0]` and `a[1]` separated by the children of `a[0]` but at the same time `a[2].a[0]` is directly followed by `a[2].a[1]` and the children come after those?

Comment: Sorry I changed it for that confusion.

Comment: @chimpsarehungry Still not congruent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing a bit the ordering of the output, so that it is the same on all levels:

```
def thing (length, depth, prefix = None):
    if not depth: return
    if not prefix: prefix = []
    for l in range (length):
        r = prefix + ['a[{}]'.format (l) ]
        yield '.'.join (r)
        for r in thing (length, depth - 1, r):
            yield r

for x in thing (2, 3): print (x)
```

---

Output is:

```
a[0]
a[0].a[0]
a[0].a[0].a[0]
a[0].a[0].a[1]
a[0].a[1]
a[0].a[1].a[0]
a[0].a[1].a[1]
a[1]
a[1].a[0]
a[1].a[0].a[0]
a[1].a[0].a[1]
a[1].a[1]
a[1].a[1].a[0]
a[1].a[1].a[1]
```

Comment: Great coding you really whipped that out

Comment: What kind of function is that

Comment: A generator. Something like a co-routine but not quite.

Comment: it sure blows up fast . thing(4,12) is going to run for 3 days on a 3.2Ghz iMac

Comment: @chimpsarehungry Why do you need it printed out? What are you going to do with these strings afterwards? What is the goal of this exercise? Maybe there is a smarter way than generating millions of strings.

Comment: I eval(string), which climbs up a hierarchy

Comment: Then I fear you are doing it wrong. Why generate a string which you then eval?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47986/discussion-between-hyperboreus-and-chimpsarehungry)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach; as Hyperboreus points out, the key is realizing that the ordering of the first-elements does not match that of the following elements; so I handle them separately.

```
from itertools import product

def item_fmt(i):
    return "a[{}]".format(repr(i))

def make_result(*args):
    return ".".join(item_fmt(arg) for arg in args)

def main():
    items    = [0, 1]
    maxdepth = 3

    for first in items:              # in order by first-item
        print(make_result(first))    # show first-item-only
        for depth in range(1, maxdepth):                # in order by depth
            for combo in product(items, repeat=depth):  # generate all combinations of given depth
                print(make_result(first, *combo))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

results in

```
a[0]
a[0].a[0]
a[0].a[1]
a[0].a[0].a[0]
a[0].a[0].a[1]
a[0].a[1].a[0]
a[0].a[1].a[1]
a[1]
a[1].a[0]
a[1].a[1]
a[1].a[0].a[0]
a[1].a[0].a[1]
a[1].a[1].a[0]
a[1].a[1].a[1]
```